# Next-auth Google Auth & Firebase Adapter

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, next-auth

When i try to use

```
 adapter: FirebaseAdapter(firestore)
```

From -> https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/firebase

**After firebase v9 the docs at next-auth hasen't been updated.**

i get this error: ***TypeError: collection is not a function***

My Code:

*Api keys, and client secret has been replaced with dots (...) to hide them.*

```js
    import NextAuth from "next-auth";
    import Providers from "next-auth/providers";
    import { FirebaseAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter";
    import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
    import { initializeApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";
    import "firebase/firestore";
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "...",
      authDomain: "...",
      projectId: "...",
      storageBucket: "...",
      messagingSenderId: "...",
      appId: "...",
      measurementId: "....",
    };
    
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    
    
    const firestore = getFirestore(app);
    
    
    const options = {
      providers: [
        Providers.Google({
          clientId:
            "...",
          clientSecret: "...",
         
        }),
      ],
    
      adapter: FirebaseAdapter(firestore),
    
      // database: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
    };
    
    export default (req, res) => {
      NextAuth(req, res, options);
    };
```

Comment: Where are you calling this file? Remember, Next is isomorphic so you have to be very precise with where you are making backend calls like this. I typically load stuff like this into a `/lib` folder.

Comment: Its in the [...nextauth].js file.

Comment: I've run into issue with environment variable visibility with Next a couple of times. I'd throw some `console.log()` into the mix and see if they are coming through, or step through your build using breakpoints in VSCode or similar.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to solve this same error using the following approach:

1- As firebase v9 is following a modular approach, pass destructured FirebaseClient object to the firebase adapter as follows

```js
// pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import { FirebaseAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter";
import { db } from "../../../firebase";

import {
  collection,
  query,
  getDocs,
  where,
  limit,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  addDoc,
  updateDoc,
  deleteDoc,
  runTransaction,
} from "firebase/firestore";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    // OAuth authentication providers
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: "",
      clientSecret: "",
    }),
  ],

  adapter: FirebaseAdapter({
    db,
    collection,
    query,
    getDocs,
    where,
    limit,
    doc,
    getDoc,
    addDoc,
    updateDoc,
    deleteDoc,
    runTransaction,
  }),
});
```

2-You might then get an error that states "cannot use toDate method of undefined", If this occurred tap into node_modules/@next-auth/firebase-adapter/dist inside index.js file replace the exports.format object with this code which adds a "?" operator after value object

```js
exports.format = {
    toFirestore(object) {
        const newObjectobject = {};
        for (const key in object) {
            const value = object[key];
            if (value === undefined)
                continue;
            newObjectobject[key] = value;
        }
        return newObjectobject;
    },
    fromFirestore(snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.exists())
            return null;
        const newUser = { ...snapshot.data(), id: snapshot.id };
        for (const key in newUser) {
            const value = newUser[key];
            if (value?.toDate)
                newUser[key] = value.toDate();
            else
                newUser[key] = value;
        }
        return newUser;
    },
};
```

3- Last thing you have to do is inside package.json remove the "^" before the next-auth version to disable package update when you do npm install which will reset all code changes occured in step 2.

This solution assumes you have firebase.js file which should look as follows

```js
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "your_api_key",
  authDomain: "your_auth_domain",
  projectId: "your_project_Id",
  storageBucket: "your_storage_bucket",
  messagingSenderId: "message_sender_Id",
  appId: "your_app_Id",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = getApps.length > 0 ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { app, db, storage };
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I thought of another solution that could work also, but I haven't tried it yet which is reverting firebase package to v8.

Comment: import { db } from "../../../firebase"; didn't work for me, I had to change to

import { initializeApp, getApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";
!getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();
const db = getFirestore();

Comment: @KarimHesham I am not able to find the second file and getting the same error as 

"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toDate') TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toDate')"

Comment: @fotoflo Well, you seem to be confusing the next-auth script with firebase.js  .. if you checked the second code block which points to firebase.js script you can find where db object is initialized.

Comment: @LonelySoul If you could reference a sample of your firebase.js and next-auth files in a sandbox or something so maybe I could have a look, meanwhile .. I have posted this question a while ago and afterwards I have successfully implemented firebase with next-auth multiple times successfully without the need for this workaround. Refer to: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup for setting up firebase in your app and https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/firebase for setting up next-auth .. if you follow along I think you can manage to get it working easily

Comment: Thanks @KarimHesham. How did you manage to get the "security rules" with firebase-adapter. I am trying to implement it and having issues.

Comment: @LonelySoul Maybe these links could be useful: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/3850 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654212/firebase-does-not-authenticate-when-using-next-auth