# Does next-auth really only works without firebase security rules?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, next-auth

I've set up `next-auth` with a google provider for my next.js application.
But I'm not seeing logged-in users or users being created after login into the app with google. Even if I set up the web client id and web client secret.
I can read and write documents in firestore without security rules but i can't get it with simple `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;` as there is no user in my **firebase cloud console** created when login in with `next-auth`.
Am I missing something or is it simply not production ready yet?

**[...nextauth].js**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { firebaseConfig } from "../../../src/lib/firebase";
// import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_WEB_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_WEB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/sign-in",
  },
  // I'M NOT WITH WORKING THE ADAPTER AT THE MOMENT
  // adapter: FirestoreAdapter({
  // apiKey: "",
  // authDomain: "",
  // projectId: "",
  // storageBucket: "",
  // messagingSenderId: "",
  // appId: "",
  // measurementId: "",
  // Optional emulator config (see below for options)
  // emulator: {},
  // }),
  // ...
});
```

**sign in**

```
{Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
                <div key={provider.name}>
                  <button
                    className={styles.signInButton}
                    onClick={() => signIn(provider.id, { callbackUrl: "/" })}
                  >
                    Sign in with {provider.name}
                  </button>
                </div>
              ))}
```

**doc creation test**

```
 const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "tests"), {
      fullName: values.fullName,
      createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
    });
```

*Seems like multiple people having this issue [Link](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/3850)

*Same issue when working with adapters, I'm not using one at the moment but tried it without success [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654212/firebase-does-not-authenticate-when-using-next-auth)

Comment: Did you find any solution, Benjamin?