# How to reuse the next-auth initFirestore object to also fetch some data from Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, next-auth

I've set up a NextJS v13.4.2 project with next-auth v4.22.1 to let users authenticate by using the 'Login with Google' button. I'm also currently using the next-auth Firebase adapter. The current files configs are:

`/app/(lib)/firestore.js`:

```js
import { initFirestore } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter";
import { cert } from "firebase-admin/app";

export const firestore = initFirestore({
    credential: cert({
        projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
        clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
        privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY,
    }),
});
```

`/app/(lib)/auth.js`:

```js
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter";
import { firestore } from "@lib/firestore";

export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    adapter: FirestoreAdapter(firestore),
};
```

`/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js`:

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "@lib/auth";

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Now, all of this works fine, but what I would like to do is to also query some data from my Firestore db and displaying it into a page. So, I thought I could do that by doing:

```js
import { firestore } from "@lib/firestore";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const citiesCol = collection(firestore, "cities");
const citiesSnapshot = await getDocs(citiesCol);
const citiesList = citiesSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
```

But sadly I get the error: `Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore`

So, my question is, can I reuse the `firestore` object (from `/app/(lib)/firestore.js`) that I'm exporting for handling the next-auth logics to also fetch some data? Or do I need to create a different [firebase config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#config-object) and initialize [Firestore again](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#access-firebase)?

Comment: `@next-auth/firebase-adapter` is a server-side package. You are meant to use it with `firebase-admin` rather than `firebase`.

Comment: @samthecodingman Okay, interesting, so basically I need to initialize Firestore following the [standard way](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#access-firebase). I was hoping I could reuse some of the configs, but I guess not (not even the credential object, since it's different from the required one)

Comment: The only reusable setting would be your project's ID. If you used the server-side credentials for the client, the clients would have unfiltered access to all of your databases and user data as the server bypasses all security and integrity checks. The purpose of the adapter is to perform queries on the server to hydrate the page with data before pushing the response to the client's device, then, your client-side code is responsible for connecting to the database and keeping that data up-to-date for the data that you want to be updated live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @samthecodingman:

> `@next-auth/firebase-adapter` is a server-side package and this is meant to use with `firebase-admin`.

You may check an example through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69876727/next-auth-google-auth-firebase-adapter).

You may also want to follow this link on [how to add Firebase to your JavaScript project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).